# What's the area of the shaded blue cresent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

This was a posted problem on a Facebook group. It was very challenging that how can you  identify the smaller radius and the larger circle's radius if the given values aren't given either on the two radiuses can anyone provide me an answer?? Both geometric  and trigonometry method?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$2R-2r=40 \implies R-r = 20$ .. (1)

[image]

Use Pythagoras to find x

$x = \sqrt{2Rr-R^2}$

Now, $x + 25 = R$

$ \implies \sqrt{2Rr-R^2} = R - 25$ .. (2)

Finally, solve (1) and (2) to get $R = 62.5$ ; $r = 42.5$

Answer (score 1):

From the geometric mean theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem, we get
$$(R-25)^2=(R-40)\cdot R,$$
that is, $R=62.5$.  From $2r=2R-40$ we have $r=42.5$.

Answer (score 0):

No need to find $r$

$(R-25)^2+20^2=(R-20)^2$

$R=62.5$

$S=\pi R^2-\pi (R-20)^2$

$S=2100\pi$

[image]

Comment: Seyed how did you get 20 ?..can you please explain how?

Comment: @Denver, Move the center of the small circle to the center of the large circle. You will easily see that the radius of the small circle is 20 less than the radius of the large circle.